# Help with interpretation of execution plan (Hash Aggregation)

Tags: sql-server, optimization, execution-plan

So I have an execution plan I'm trying to optimise, and there's a section of an operator I can't quite understand.

There is a section of the plan where a Compute Scalar is used, followed by an aggregation using a hash match.

I have a questions:

How can I use the properties of the hash match aggregator to tell me which columns it is outputting? I can't tell which columns the aggregation is being performed on.

This is the section of the plan:
[image]

This is the operator properties:

[image]

Plan XML for the element:

```
<RelOp NodeId="489" PhysicalOp="Hash Match" LogicalOp="Aggregate" EstimateRows="25432.8" EstimateIO="0" EstimateCPU="621.202" AvgRowSize="1038" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="12113" Parallel="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Staging]" Schema="[Junifer]" Table="[BillBreakdownLine]" Alias="[bbl]" Column="id" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Staging]" Schema="[Junifer]" Table="[BillBreakdownLine]" Alias="[bbl]" Column="description" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Staging]" Schema="[Junifer]" Table="[BillBreakdownLine]" Alias="[bbl]" Column="unitPrice" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Staging]" Schema="[Junifer]" Table="[BillBreakdownLine]" Alias="[bbl]" Column="units" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[Staging]" Schema="[Junifer]" Table="[BillBreakdownLine]" Alias="[bbl]" Column="billCurrencyAmount" />
                    <ColumnReference Table="#BillLineCategorisation" Alias="[blc]" Column="Item" />
                    <ColumnReference Table="#BillLineCategorisation" Alias="[blc]" Column="InvoiceLineCategory" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1066" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1067" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1068" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1069" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1070" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1071" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1072" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1073" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1074" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1075" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1076" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1077" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1078" />
                    <ColumnReference Column="Expr1079" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <MemoryFractions Input="0.00395919" Output="0.379612" />
                  <Hash>
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Staging]" Schema="[Junifer]" Table="[BillBreakdownLine]" Alias="[bbl]" Column="description" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="ANY([Staging].[Junifer].[BillBreakdownLine].[description] as [bbl].[description])">
                          <Aggregate Distinct="0" AggType="ANY">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[Staging]" Schema="[Junifer]" Table="[BillBreakdownLine]" Alias="[bbl]" Column="description" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Aggregate>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Staging]" Schema="[Junifer]" Table="[BillBreakdownLine]" Alias="[bbl]" Column="unitPrice" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="ANY([Staging].[Junifer].[BillBreakdownLine].[unitPrice] as [bbl].[unitPrice])">
                          <Aggregate Distinct="0" AggType="ANY">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[Staging]" Schema="[Junifer]" Table="[BillBreakdownLine]" Alias="[bbl]" Column="unitPrice" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Aggregate>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Staging]" Schema="[Junifer]" Table="[BillBreakdownLine]" Alias="[bbl]" Column="units" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="ANY([Staging].[Junifer].[BillBreakdownLine].[units] as [bbl].[units])">
                          <Aggregate Distinct="0" AggType="ANY">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[Staging]" Schema="[Junifer]" Table="[BillBreakdownLine]" Alias="[bbl]" Column="units" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Aggregate>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[Staging]" Schema="[Junifer]" Table="[BillBreakdownLine]" Alias="[bbl]" Column="billCurrencyAmount" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="ANY([Staging].[Junifer].[BillBreakdownLine].[billCurrencyAmount] as [bbl].[billCurrencyAmount])">
                          <Aggregate Distinct="0" AggType="ANY">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[Staging]" Schema="[Junifer]" Table="[BillBreakdownLine]" Alias="[bbl]" Column="billCurrencyAmount" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Aggregate>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1077" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="ANY([Expr1077])">
                          <Aggregate Distinct="0" AggType="ANY">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1077" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Aggregate>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1078" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="ANY([Expr1078])">
                          <Aggregate Distinct="0" AggType="ANY">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1078" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Aggregate>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1079" />
                        <ScalarOperator ScalarString="ANY([Expr1079])">
                          <Aggregate Distinct="0" AggType="ANY">
                            <ScalarOperator>
                              <Identifier>
                                <ColumnReference Column="Expr1079" />
                              </Identifier>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </Aggregate>
                        </ScalarOperator>
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <HashKeysBuild>
                      <ColumnReference Database="[Staging]" Schema="[Junifer]" Table="[BillBreakdownLine]" Alias="[bbl]" Column="id" />
                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1066" />
                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1067" />
                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1068" />
                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1069" />
                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1070" />
                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1071" />
                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1072" />
                      <ColumnReference Table="#BillLineCategorisation" Alias="[blc]" Column="Item" />
                      <ColumnReference Table="#BillLineCategorisation" Alias="[blc]" Column="InvoiceLineCategory" />
                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1073" />
                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1074" />
                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1075" />
                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1076" />
                    </HashKeysBuild>
                    <BuildResidual>
                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[Staging].[Junifer].[BillBreakdownLine].[id] as [bbl].[id] = [Staging].[Junifer].[BillBreakdownLine].[id] as [bbl].[id] AND [Expr1066] = [Expr1066] AND [Expr1067] = [Expr1067] AND [Expr1068] = [Expr1068] AND [Expr1069] = [Expr1069] AND [Expr1070] = [Expr1070] AND [Expr1071] = [Expr1071] AND [Expr1072] = [Expr1072] AND #BillLineCategorisation.[Item] as [blc].[Item] = #BillLineCategorisation.[Item] as [blc].[Item] AND #BillLineCategorisation.[InvoiceLineCategory] as [blc].[InvoiceLineCategory] = #BillLineCategorisation.[InvoiceLineCategory] as [blc].[InvoiceLineCategory] AND [Expr1073] = [Expr1073] AND [Expr1074] = [Expr1074] AND [Expr1075] = [Expr1075] AND [Expr1076] = [Expr1076]">
                        <Logical Operation="AND">

                                  ...                                                                             <Logical Operation="AND">
                                                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                                                            <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                                                <Identifier>
                                                                                  <ColumnReference Database="[Staging]" Schema="[Junifer]" Table="[BillBreakdownLine]" Alias="[bbl]" Column="id" />
                                                                                </Identifier>
                                                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                                                <Identifier>
                                                                                  <ColumnReference Database="[Staging]" Schema="[Junifer]" Table="[BillBreakdownLine]" Alias="[bbl]" Column="id" />
                                                                                </Identifier>
                                                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                                                            </Compare>
                                                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                                                            <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                                                <Identifier>
                                                                                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1066" />
                                                                                </Identifier>
                                                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                                                <Identifier>
                                                                                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1066" />
                                                                                </Identifier>
                                                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                                                            </Compare>
                                                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                                                        </Logical>
                                                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                                                        <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                                                            <Identifier>
                                                                              <ColumnReference Column="Expr1067" />
                                                                            </Identifier>
                                                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                                                            <Identifier>
                                                                              <ColumnReference Column="Expr1067" />
                                                                            </Identifier>
                                                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                                                        </Compare>
                                                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                                                    </Logical>
                                                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                                                    <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                                                        <Identifier>
                                                                          <ColumnReference Column="Expr1068" />
                                                                        </Identifier>
                                                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                                                        <Identifier>
                                                                          <ColumnReference Column="Expr1068" />
                                                                        </Identifier>
                                                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                                                    </Compare>
                                                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                                                </Logical>
                                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                                <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                                                    <Identifier>
                                                                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1069" />
                                                                    </Identifier>
                                                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                                                    <Identifier>
                                                                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1069" />
                                                                    </Identifier>
                                                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                                                </Compare>
                                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                                            </Logical>
                                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                                            <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                                <Identifier>
                                                                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1070" />
                                                                </Identifier>
                                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                                <Identifier>
                                                                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1070" />
                                                                </Identifier>
                                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                                            </Compare>
                                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                                        </Logical>
                                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                                        <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                                            <Identifier>
                                                              <ColumnReference Column="Expr1071" />
                                                            </Identifier>
                                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                                            <Identifier>
                                                              <ColumnReference Column="Expr1071" />
                                                            </Identifier>
                                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                                        </Compare>
                                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                                    </Logical>
                                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                                    <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                                        <Identifier>
                                                          <ColumnReference Column="Expr1072" />
                                                        </Identifier>
                                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                                        <Identifier>
                                                          <ColumnReference Column="Expr1072" />
                                                        </Identifier>
                                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                                    </Compare>
                                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                                </Logical>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                                    <Identifier>
                                                      <ColumnReference Table="#BillLineCategorisation" Alias="[blc]" Column="Item" />
                                                    </Identifier>
                                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                                    <Identifier>
                                                      <ColumnReference Table="#BillLineCategorisation" Alias="[blc]" Column="Item" />
                                                    </Identifier>
                                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                                </Compare>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                            </Logical>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Identifier>
                                                  <ColumnReference Table="#BillLineCategorisation" Alias="[blc]" Column="InvoiceLineCategory" />
                                                </Identifier>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                              <ScalarOperator>
                                                <Identifier>
                                                  <ColumnReference Table="#BillLineCategorisation" Alias="[blc]" Column="InvoiceLineCategory" />
                                                </Identifier>
                                              </ScalarOperator>
                                            </Compare>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                        </Logical>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Identifier>
                                              <ColumnReference Column="Expr1073" />
                                            </Identifier>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                          <ScalarOperator>
                                            <Identifier>
                                              <ColumnReference Column="Expr1073" />
                                            </Identifier>
                                          </ScalarOperator>
                                        </Compare>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Logical>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Identifier>
                                          <ColumnReference Column="Expr1074" />
                                        </Identifier>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                      <ScalarOperator>
                                        <Identifier>
                                          <ColumnReference Column="Expr1074" />
                                        </Identifier>
                                      </ScalarOperator>
                                    </Compare>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </Logical>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Identifier>
                                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1075" />
                                    </Identifier>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                  <ScalarOperator>
                                    <Identifier>
                                      <ColumnReference Column="Expr1075" />
                                    </Identifier>
                                  </ScalarOperator>
                                </Compare>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Logical>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Compare CompareOp="IS">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1076" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1076" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </Logical>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </BuildResidual>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried opening the execution plan with Sentry One Plan Explorer? It's free and will allow you to see what the different expressions are doing. Also, if you could paste the XML for the execution into pastetheplan.com and give us the link it would help a lot.

Comment: Yeah the screenshots are from Sentry Plan Explorer. Paste the plan won't accept XML over 2mb, which this is. Are there any particular parts I can provide?

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't aware of that restriction in pastetheplan. have you checked the expressions tab at the bottom of plan explorer to see what each expression is being based on?

Comment: Yeah - added a picture and none of those seem to be aggregations. The only ones I can see for hash match aggregate are for 1077,1078,1079, which are for some comparisons to static strings. Could that be related at all?

Comment: Do you have `DISTINCT` keyword in your query?

Comment: Yeah DISTINCT is used in the final statements, and final CTE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I use the properties of the hash match aggregator to tell me
>   which columns it is outputting?

It is clearly shown in the output list of your XML. Where you see the expressions you need to work back and find out what the expression definition is.

As I cannot see your full query and execution plan I will use an example to show how you can get that information.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [PickedQuantity]
    FROM [WideWorldImporters].[Sales].[OrderLines]
```

[image]

In this case it is `PickedQuantity`.[image]

Now if I extend the same query to you will see the column comparisons that you are seeing in your case.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [PickedQuantity], 
    [LastEditedBy], 
    [LastEditedWhen]
FROM 
    [WideWorldImporters].[Sales].[OrderLines]
```

[image]

You can see the same in XML.[image]

> I can't tell which columns the aggregation is being performed on.

As you said you have distinct in your select statement I am assuming that is why you are seeing the `Hash Aggregate` operator. You can see in the above example use of `Hash Aggregate` for implementing `DISTINCT`.

This [article](http://web.archive.org/web/20170606142356/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/04/is-distinct-aggregation-still-considered-harmful.aspx) by Paul White gives more insight with complex examples.

This [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/09/20/hash-aggregate/) by Craig Freedman shows example of hash aggregate being used to implement `DISTINCT`.

Comment: So just to confirm, there is nothing I can necessarily look at "at a glance" to see that this aggregation is a distinct sort? I have to infer it from the outputted columns? It is difficult for me as my head doesn't think of a distinct sort as being an aggregation. Is the build residual of [ColumnA] = [ColumnA], [ColumnB] = [ColumnB] etc the fact that the engine is comparing the data set to itself to form a distinct list in that case?

Comment: @George.Palacios I did edit the answer by adding additional columns to the select statement.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll need to remember this operator and pattern in future!